# parse uploaded file to another format before saving it in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload csv file and then parse to xml format but before saving it "import csv file and save it as xml file"
I have got the uploading functionality working fine and be saved correctly; however, my issue is how to pass the uploaded file to the function where it is parsed to xml format.
I am using django python

Model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from .validators import validate_file_extension

# Create your models here.
class DataFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    file = models.FileField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title + ' - ' +  self.description + ' - ' + self.file
```

and here is my form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import DataFile


class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DataFile
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'file' ]
```

here is my view.py

```
def importing(request):
    form = FileForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            #here is where the passing supose to be 
            form = csv2xml(request.FILES['file']) 

            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000')

    return render(request, 'import.html', { 'form': form })
```

**UPDATE:**
function that i want to pass my uploaded file to:

```
def csv2xml(csv_file):
    xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(csv_file)

    return xml
```

I want the file to be passed to csv2xml function, converted, and then save it as xml

When I use the above way to pass it to the function it says:

```
AttributeError at /importing
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: Try this, `form = csv2xml(request.FILES['file'].read())` instead of `form = csv2xml(request.FILES['file'])`

Comment: I tried it. didn't work. It says "AttributeError at /importing
'bytes' object has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: Can you add the function definition of `csv2xml()` ?

Comment: Do you mean the function itself? csv2xml() is added in above question.. but i edited a little bit. please see the updated one above

Comment: Yes, That what i meant

Comment: can you see the updated one

Comment: Can you check the`type(form)` before you call `form.save()` ?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is to make some changes in the `save` method of `models.Model` class. Something like this in `models.py`:

```
class DataFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    file = models.FileField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.file:
            """ Do Whatever you wanna do with the upload file here """
        super(DataFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will make necessary changes to the uploaded file before it go and save on the server.

Comment: {
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  if self.file:
   self.file = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(self.file)
  super(DataFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
 
} 

I did this but still gives me this error "'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'"

Comment: Would you mind updating the question with the full details of error? and which line caused the error.